# IE bug with span's width in button. Span in button can't be wider than button size

Tags: html, css

In IE button inner element - span doesn't work correctly. Size of span can't go beyond buttons borders. How can i fix it?

```
<div class="book_button_container">
  <button class="book_button">Записаться на бесплатный замер
    <span class="book_button_inner_border"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="price_button_container">
  <button class="price_button">Узнать стоимость кухни
    <span class="price_button_inner_border"></span>
  </button>
</div>

.book_button,
.price_button {
  position: relative;
  width: 425px;
}

.book_button_inner_border,
.price_button_inner_border {
    width: 440px;
    height: 85%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

[image: Buttons in Chrome, Firefox and other Chromium browsers]
[image: Buttons in Internet Explorer]